# Displaying a png in subplot2grid

Tags: matplotlib, png, subplot

I want to generate a figure with several subplots. In two of the subplots I want to display a png image. While this works if I want to display the image by itself:

```
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    image1 = mpimg.imread('DDO69.png')
    plt.imshow(image1)
```

I haven't been able to stitch this in my subplot2grid code block, as in:

```
sub1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (0,0), colspan=3)
sub1 = mpimg.imread('DDO69.png')
```

I haven't seen any examples of this in tutorials or here so I am somewhat stuck. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the current axes with [plt.sca()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.sca) before calling imshow().

```
sub1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (0,0), colspan=3)
plt.sca(sub1)
plt.imshow(image1)
```

or you can call the imshow method on the [axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html):

```
sub1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (0,0), colspan=3)
sub1.imshow(image1)
```

In the example above you are overwritting sub1 which might be part of your problem.